# How can I scrollToTop in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI, but I have a problem... How can I scroll to top in `ScrollView` when the `SegmentedControl` value changed?

This is code for the main view to show Data:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        SegmentedControl(selection: $selected) {
            Text("Food").tag(0)
            Text("Drinks").tag(1)
            Text("Wines").tag(2)
            }
            .padding()
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                if selected == 0 {
                    ForEach (persons) {
                        AnyCell(person: $0, animal: nil, wine: nil)
                    }
                } else if selected == 1 {
                    ForEach (animals) {
                        AnyCell(person: nil, animal: $0, wine: nil)
                    }
                } else {
                    ForEach (wines) {
                        AnyCell(person: nil, animal: nil, wine: $0)
                    }
                }
            }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Food list"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us some more information about what's in the scroll view? Is the segmented control supposed to filter the contents of the scroll view? Or is it supposed to replace them entirely?

Comment: When I change a value in Segmented control I get new content(rows) in Scroll view. In the Scroll view there are some dummy Views.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us the code you've tried?

Comment: I just tried to add SegmentedControl and ScrollView with cells, but I didn't find any function like changeValue in SegmentedControl...

Comment: Post what you have so we have something to work off of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SwiftUI, if you change the value of a variable, any of the `body` properties that depend on it will be recomputed. In your case, just changing the selection will completely reset the `ScrollView`.

I had to fill in a bunch of missing pieces (please include ALL of the relevant code in the future), but here's what I have:

```
import SwiftUI

let people = ["John", "Sarah", "Cathy"]
let animals = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Bird", "Lion", "Snake", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Bird", "Lion", "Snake"]
let wines = ["Sauvignon Blanc", "Syrah", "Pinot Noir", "Champagne", "Sauvignon Blanc", "Syrah", "Pinot Noir", "Champagne", "Sauvignon Blanc", "Syrah", "Pinot Noir", "Champagne", "Sauvignon Blanc", "Syrah", "Pinot Noir", "Champagne"]

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var selected: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SegmentedControl(selection: $selected) {
                    Text("Food").tag(0)
                    Text("Drinks").tag(1)
                    Text("Wines").tag(2)
                    }
                    .padding()

                    if selected == 0 {
                        ScrollView {
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                ForEach (people.identified(by: \.self)) {
                                    CellView(title: $0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else if selected == 1 {
                        ScrollView {
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                ForEach (animals.identified(by: \.self)) {
                                    CellView(title: $0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        ScrollView {
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                ForEach (wines.identified(by: \.self)) {
                                    CellView(title: $0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Food list"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct CellView : View {
    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(title).font(.largeTitle).frame(height: 100).background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

When you change `selected`, the `ScrollView` will be recreated, which will leave its scroller at the top. To test it out, tap "Wines", scroll down a bit, and then tap either of the others.

[image: In action]

Comment: It won't scroll to top... it is what I want.

Comment: This starts the `ScrollView`'s content at the top when you switch tabs on the `SegmentedControl`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I want to scroll to top of the  Scroll View when I change value o SegmentedControl, but your code doesn't work like that.

Comment: Have you tried running it? That's exactly what it does... Or are you saying you want the current view to scroll back to its top before switching? Perhaps you can provide an animation in the question showing what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Yea I tried it. Try yourself... Try to add more animals to animals and then click on wines... It won't scroll to top...

Comment: Ah! This is why you should include ALL of the relevant code. I wouldn't have been able to reproduce that without having your data :/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change the identity of a ScrollView when displaying new content is by assigning it an id. In the given example, this can be achieved by using `selected` state.

```
ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                if selected == 0 {
                    ForEach (persons) {
                        AnyCell(person: $0, animal: nil, wine: nil)
                    }
                } else if selected == 1 {
                    ForEach (animals) {
                        AnyCell(person: nil, animal: $0, wine: nil)
                    }
                } else {
                    ForEach (wines) {
                        AnyCell(person: nil, animal: nil, wine: $0)
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

It's important to note that the position of each list will be maintained independently. If scrolling to the top is required all the times, one possible solution is to rotate the id (e.g. using a random number). While not ideal, it may be possible to find a better solution in the future.